# how to make image view drag and drop on gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop, imageview, touch-event

i want to Override the onTouch event and get the image view from the gridview
and drag it to new place on the grid ?

Comment: I see several different challenges for this functionality:
  1) dragging a view
  2) detecting between which views you've dropped the transient view
  3) updating the adapter to reflect the changes in the the view order.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for, but here's a drag-and-drop grid I developed that might help you:

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

It allows you to long press a child view and drag it to another position in the grid. It's animated, too!

Comment: wow.... Amazing work. What were u thinking when u worked on this,.. This is so perfect. Thanks